# How much extra should I expect to pay to have a Turbo replaced at the dealership as opposed to at a garage?

Tags: ford, fiesta, turbocharger

The turbo on a Ford Fiesta 2008 TDCi is bust.

How much should I expect to pay?

Comment: Do you intend to go to the dealership? They tend to be more expensive than most third parties but you do get a few extra benefits with that. Also you can get new and used parts of Ebay really cheaply if you are willing to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks. The price i'm interested in is the average price of a garage repair (non-dealership) with a new part.

Comment: Richard, this really isn't answerable here - in fact it is explicitly off topic (see [ask]) because it will vary by location, time, type of car, market forces etc

Comment: Richard, this question isn't a good fit for the site because any number that will be mentioned here will become obsolete very quickly.

Comment: @richardstelmach Might I suggest you rephrase the question (by editing it) as ***How much extra should I expect to pay to have a Turbo replaced at the dealership as opposed to at a garage?*** This allows for more structure to peoples answers due to the pros and cons associated with each, as well as making it applicable to more people, rather than just being about the price (which will vary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two routes; dealership and third party (a normal garage mechanic).

### Dealership

If you were to get it done at the dealership, you can expect to pay 10-30% more on top of what an independent garage might charge you. The advantage to going this route is that generally you are going to get what you pay for when it comes to a turbo replacement. There is generally a lot of labour time that goes in to ensuring the part, and any other parts that the new part could effect, works perfectly (that other garages often skip out to save money) in order to avoid other parts failing in the future! You also get genuine parts, a Ford dealer stamp in your service book (which will effect the value of your car on the used market) and the peace of mind knowing that the work is being carried out by properly trained and manufacturer approved mechanics.

Note that the dealerships do often price match within a 5 mile or so radius so you may actually get a really good price there if you do your research first.

### Garage

The other option is to go the non-dealership route. This is the way most people go due to the inherent price savings associated with this for what most people might assume as being the "same" work done. I would say this is still your best bet for getting the cheapest quote for the work that needs doing, however I will make you aware of the following things that you may want to take note of:
- They don't necessarily use manufacturer approved parts
- They can skip out some of the tests to ensure there will be no negative knock-on effect to the work being carried out
- Will result in a less valuable service history (and therefore resale value of the car)

That being said, I would say that it is okay to have the work done at the garage as long as you understand what you are getting, their inherent advantages and disadvantages and also that you should go to someone you trust or have been recommended to *by* someone knowledgeable that you trust.

> How much should I expect to pay to have a Turbo replaced?

About £150-£200 for a new turbo plus labour, which I can't estimate easily as it varies significantly depending on where you go. Also the time it takes will vary depending on the level of expertise of the mechanic and whether they are having a good day or not (luck). Hence my previous recommendation that was you should ***go to someone you trust***!

If you don't trust anyone then you can come back with only a quote and break it down as follows to find out for yourself whether it is a good value or not.

For example you were quoted £600 for a turbo replacement that would take 4 hours:

- £600 (total) - £200 (parts) = £400 (labour cost)
- £400 divided by 4 hours = £100 per hour

So in this example you would be paying £100 per hour for labour and £200 for the part itself. Both of these prices seem quite expensive for a garage (but more reasonable for a dealership). I would make an educated guess that you should pay about £400-500 for the work that you need done at a garage including parts if you can find a reputable, trustworthy garage.

All costs used here are estimates so take them with a pinch of salt and do your own research as prices can change on a regular basis, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: thanks, this is handy information. I understand it can vary massively, but the ballpark figure is useful and matches up to other quotes and research i've done. I'd probably more expect £250 for the part and up to a days work. So the hourly rate thing you've done there is handy. Makes sense as i was expecting between £550 and £1100.

Comment: @richardstelmach Okay that's fair enough, I didn't know exactly how long it could take so I just gave a hyperthetical situation. Glad I could help.